# Woocommerce confirm password not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have added the following code to my functions.php file to allow password confirmation on the checkout page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'wc_add_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {
        $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password2'] = array(
            'type'              => 'password',
            'label'             => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'          => true,
            'placeholder'       => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
}
// Check the password and confirm password fields match before allow checkout to proceed.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );
function wc_check_confirm_password_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_password2'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the site checkout page. You will have to add a product to the cart and then go back to the checkout page. Once a product is in the cart and you are on the Checkout page you will notice that the password field has been highlighted red and there is no password confirmation field. This is broken.

http://staging.vawk.ca/checkout/

However if you go to the following url and do the same thing the password confirmation is there and everything works correctly. As far as I am concerned all of the code is the same and the database is the same.

http://jolangreen.com/other/clients/vawk/checkout/

How can I get the password confirmation to work on http://staging.vawk.ca/checkout/

Answer (score 0):

Please try the modified code below, working on WordPress 4.7.3+ with WooCommerce 3.0.3+.

logicdigger

```
**
 * Add a confirm password field to the checkout registration form.
 */
function o_woocommerce_confirm_password_checkout( $checkout ) {
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'no' ) {

        $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields();

        $fields['account']['account_confirm_password'] = array(
            'type'              => 'password',
            'label'             => __( 'Confirm password', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'          => true,
            'placeholder'       => _x( 'Confirm Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' )
        );

        $checkout->__set( 'checkout_fields', $fields );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'o_woocommerce_confirm_password_checkout', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Validate that the two password fields match.
 */
function o_woocommerce_confirm_password_validation( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( $checkout->must_create_account || ! empty( $posted['createaccount'] ) ) ) {
        if ( strcmp( $posted['account_password'], $posted['account_confirm_password'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'o_woocommerce_confirm_password_validation', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This Works! The password input field still outlines as red or invalid on page load but that is something that I can figure out.